# serializeasync object to utf8jsonwriter with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

In dotnet3.1, using System.Text.Json

How to asynchronous serialize a c# object to a utf8jsonwriter ?
I find the Serialize() method but not the Async version and I'm writing to a stream so I'm having error:
"Error while copying to stream... Synchronous operations are disallowed...." if I use sync Serialize()

my code is very simple:

```
Stream responseStream;
var jsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(responseStream);
await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(jsonWriter, obj);
```

where obj is an class instance DTO.

I see there is an overload receiving a Stream but I need to write using the Utf8JsonWriter jsonWriter which wraps the target stream.

Comment: There are two methods documented for direct async serialization to a stream: [`JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(Stream, Object, Type, JsonSerializerOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializeasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializeAsync_System_IO_Stream_System_Object_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) ...

Comment: ... and [`JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<TValue>(Stream, TValue, JsonSerializerOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializeasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializeAsync__1_System_IO_Stream___0_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).  Won't those do what you need?  Can you give an example of why you need to serialize to `Utf8JsonWriter` instead?

Comment: I'm saying that I need to write to Utf8JsonWriter and not to Stream. the code in the question is very simplified, at the moment to Serialize I only have the utf8writer and not the underlying stream. btw already tested forcing writing directly to stream and output is not correct, also tested writing synchronously to utf8writer and works good, but as I say, I need to write in async way.

Comment: @user810917 why? `Utf8JsonWriter` doesn't serialize, it only emits JSON text. `JsonSerializer` [uses Utf8JsonWriter](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Stream.cs#L45) to emit JSON. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: Looks like, in .Net 3.1 at least, they haven't made an API for that public.  [`SerializeAsync(Stream, ...)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Stream.cs) eventually calls [`WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, ...)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Stream.cs#L45) which serializes portions to a `PooledByteBufferWriter` then copies asynchronously to the stream.  But there's nothing similar that is public for `Utf8JsonWriter`.

Comment: @dbc they don't have to. Stream serialization [*uses* Utf8JsonWriter](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Stream.cs#L45), not the other way round. Whatever the OP's problem is, it can't be solved by "serializing" to the writer

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned they are already two documented methods for async serialization to stream. Though if your JSON serializer is synchronously writing to the response body, then you have to enable SynchronousIO.

Kestrel (Program.cs class):

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
                {
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                })
```

IIS (Startup.cs class):

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
  options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
```

Comment: already tested and it works but I want to avoid forcing Sync. I would like a have an async solutions. thnks